# Product Array with loops

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I'm building a spreadsheet and trying to get to a productivity total per employee per day. The equation is easy --> (activity 1 * cycle time 1) + (activity 2 * cycle time 2).....
I have x amount of columns (they change each time) and y amount of rows (which grow daily).  A sample of the data looks as follows:

Date      | Name     | Act 1| CT 1| Act 2| CT 2| Productivity

1/15/2016 | Jonathan | 20   | 2   | 10   | 1.5 | .....

1/14/2016 | Billy    | 19   | 2   | 10   | 1.5 | .....

How can I automate the equation of (act 1 * Ct1) + (Act 2 * Ct2) to the nth, keeping everything dynamic?

I feel like I need to store the Activities in an array and the Cycle Times in another and then multiply the two arrays.  I'm not sure how to do this as I'm very fresh on arrays and pretty amature on VBA. I've been thinking about other ways to do this but haven't been able to come up with any.

Can someone help me?  Explanations in full would be appreciated too. :)

```
    Sub InsertColumnsAndFormulasUntilEndOfProductivityTable_MakeProductivityNumbers()

With Sheet6
    Set EmployeesRange = .Range("A1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown))
End With

With Sheet1
    Set ActivityRange = .Range("A1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown))
End With

'insert column (For i = 1...) and then vlookup (FormulaRange1.Formula...)
With Sheet4
    y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    x = (.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) * 2
    Startrow = 2
    StartColumn = 2


    For i = 1 + StartColumn To (x + 1) Step 2
        .Columns(i).EntireColumn.Insert
        Set FormulaRange1 = .Range(.Cells(Startrow, i), .Cells(y, i))

           If i = 3 Then
                'insert title for usernames and then vlookup
                Cells(Startrow - 1, i).Value = Cells(Startrow - 1, i - 1).Value & "'s Team"
                FormulaRange1.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(R[0]C[-1],'" & EmployeesRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & EmployeesRange.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1) & ", 2, False)"

            ElseIf i <= x Then
                'insert title for activities and then vlookup lock row 1
                Cells(Startrow - 1, i).Value = Cells(Startrow - 1, i - 1).Value & " Cycle Time"
                FormulaRange1.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(R1C[-1],'" & ActivityRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & ActivityRange.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1) & ", 2, False)"
            Else
                'Sum totals of productivity per person per day
                Cells(Startrow - 1, i - 1).Value = "Totals"

                'THIS IS WHERE THE PRODUCTIVITY EQUATION/LOOP NEEDS TO GO!...

           End If
    Next




End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hope you can try table format http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/tables.html

Comment: Hi Linga,
I'm trying to do everything in VBA - your link suggests building a table manually... do I have that correct?  I've also thought of building out a table with copy and paste loops but figured there was a beter way through arrays. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to create a user defined function (UDF) that you can enter at the end of your data. The function below defines the range of the data for a single day/user, i.e. a single row. Quick and simple.

My test data was set up like this:

[image]

In the Productivity column, each cell has the formula:

`=CalcProductivity(C2:J2)`

The UDF is defined in a VBA module like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CalcProductivity(dataRange As Range) As Double
    '--- input range is 'n' pairs of activity,cycle data.
    '    productivity is calculated by the sum of all activity * cycle pairs
    Dim dataArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim runningSum As Double

    dataArray = dataRange     'copy to memory array for speed

    runningSum = 0#
    For i = 1 To UBound(dataArray, 2) Step 2
        runningSum = runningSum + (dataArray(1, i) * dataArray(1, i + 1))
    Next i
    CalcProductivity = runningSum
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @PeterT,Thanks for the advice. It doesn't seem to be working for me. To be honest I'm a bit lost. Perhaps if I can get a bit of clarification I can try to change things to make it work.  What does the # in runningSum represent? Also I don't understand the runningSum equation in the loop - It seems to read: Take the second column in this row and add it to the dataArray(which is a function of i) [this makes sense to me]... and then take that number and times it by the data array offseted by one [***dataArray(1, i +1)].  But were are we holding that second dataArray?

Comment: btw this is how i entered it into my vba editor... maybe I did that wrong?

Else
                Cells(Startrow - 1, i - 1).Value = "Productivity"
                FormulaRange1.Offset(0, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "=CalcProductivity(dataRange)"
                
           End If

Comment: The # in the `runningSum` assignment is how VBA represents a double precision floating point number. If you type in `runningSum = 0.0`, the VBA editor will change it to read `runningSum = 0#`. The equation multiplies the Activity value `dataArray(1,i)` by the Cycle value `dataArray(1,i+1) and adds it to the sum of the previous productivity values. Because the loop steps by 2, the Activity value will always be (i) and the Cycle value will always be (i+1).

Comment: The solution I've suggested bypasses all of the code listed in your original post. If you copy/paste the `CalcProductivity` function as written above, then in a cell on the same row as your data type in `=CalcProductivity(<yourstartingcell>:<yourendingcell>)` it fill that cell with your total Productivity value.

Comment: Ok I see - thanks for clarifying.  When i manually enter the CalcProducitivity into the worksheet it displays the correct numbers.

When I try it in VBA I keep getting a Subscript our of range error (Run Time Error 9).  The error is over "dataArray(1, i + 1))".... it seems to add up the numbers and store them in runningSum until the very end. One thing I noticed is that Ubound shows a number of 69 but there are actually 72 columns. How can I fix this?

Comment: Forget the above comment -- i wasn't defining the data range properly...still trying to debug another issue tho :s

Comment: Make sure that the range entered in the formula on the spreadsheet covers ONLY the data and does NOT include the date or name. As long as you have all the pairs of data (activity*cycle), the productivity calculation should work correctly. UBound will match the number of columns in the `dataRange` passed into the function. So if UBound says there's 69 values in the array, then the `Range` passed into the function has 69 columns.

Comment: I see that now.  I'm not sure how to create a range for all the pairs of data and then have it run for every row in my data.  For example... how did you get rows 3 to be a different number than row 4.  What was your <yourstartingcell>:<yourendingcell> in your =CalcProducitivity equation?

Comment: Each row's last cell calculates Productivity for ONLY that row. So, in my test data worksheet above, the range in row 2 is `=CalcProductivity(C2:J2)`, row 3 is `=CalcProductivity(C3:J3)`, row 4 is `=CalcProductivity(C4:J4)`, and so on...

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work for me... 
I found another solution however! Thanks for all your help I promise it will go to a good cause (my first major automation project at work). I will post the final code below... essentially I made a loop through the value range where the row (j) adds one after each iteration. - Jon

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub InsertColumnsAndFormulasUntilEndOfProductivityTable_MakeProductivityNumbers()

With Sheet6
    Set EmployeesRange = .Range("A1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown))
End With

With Sheet1
    Set ActivityRange = .Range("A1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown))
End With

'insert column (For i = 1...) and then vlookup (FormulaRange1.Formula...)
With Sheet4
    y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim j As Long
    x = (.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) * 2
    Startrow = 2
    StartColumn = 2
    j = ActiveCell.Row


    For i = 1 + StartColumn To (x + 1) Step 2
        .Columns(i).EntireColumn.Insert
        Set FormulaRange1 = .Range(.Cells(Startrow, i), .Cells(y, i))

           If i = 3 Then
                'insert title for usernames and then vlookup
                Cells(Startrow - 1, i).Value = Cells(Startrow - 1, i - 1).Value & "'s Team"
                FormulaRange1.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(R[0]C[-1],'" & EmployeesRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & EmployeesRange.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1) & ", 2, False)"

            ElseIf i <= x Then
                'insert title for activities and then vlookup lock row 1
                Cells(Startrow - 1, i).Value = Cells(Startrow - 1, i - 1).Value & " Cycle Time"
                FormulaRange1.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(R1C[-1],'" & ActivityRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & ActivityRange.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1) & ", 2, False)"
            Else
                'Sum totals of productivity per person per day
                'the loop is for each row, to ensure a productivity number per person
                Cells(Startrow - 1, i - 1).Value = "Totals"
                For j = 2 To y
                Set DataRange2 = .Range(.Cells(j, StartColumn + 2), .Cells(j, i))
                Cells(j, i - 1).Value = CalcProductivity(DataRange2)
                Next


           End If
    Next




End With
End Sub
```

'function to find the productivity number (row1*column1)+(row2*column2)...

```
Public Function CalcProductivity(dataRange As Range) As Double
    '--- input range is 'n' pairs of activity,cycle data.
    '    productivity is calculated by the sum of all activity * cycle pairs
    Dim dataArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long, t As Long
    Dim runningSum As Double


    dataArray = dataRange     'copy to memory array for speed

    runningSum = 0#

    For i = 1 To UBound(dataArray, 2) Step 2
        runningSum = runningSum + (dataArray(1, i) * dataArray(1, i + 1))
    Next
    CalcProductivity = runningSum

End Function
```